# In html5 to set a checkbox as checked, should I simply use checked (as a property) or checked="checked" ( as an attribute)?

Tags: html, xhtml

Currently in our plugin we were setting the checkboxes as checked by setting

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

This was to preserve xhtml compatibility. I'm more used to setting checked as a property

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

What is the correct way to proceed in html5?Should we still care about xhtml compatibility?

Comment: Note that you don't need the `/>` in HTML5, either.

Comment: That's not a property, that's still an attribute. You're only setting the property if you do it in a script, or anywhere else that calls it a property. But in HTML and XML markup, it's called an attribute.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is an attribute in either case. And it sets a value (the same value, `true`) on a DOM property of the element node in either case.

For most purposes, it does not matter which syntax you use. However, there are some points to note:

- If you use HTML5 in XML serialization (“XHTML5”), you must use `checked="checked"`.
- In styling, the syntaxes are not quite equivalent when using attribute selectors (the shorter form does not match `[checked=checked]`), but this does not matter in practice: `[checked]` matches checked checkboxes in either case.
- The clumsy syntax `checked="checked"` is a holdover from SGML and included for compatibility only, so it may make your code look old-fashioned (which rarely matters).

Comment: Was that syntax a holdover from SGML that was carried into XHTML (as opposed to XML)?

Comment: The `checked="checked"` syntax was carried into XML as well. HTML5 is not based on SGML or XML, so it can define its own syntax in a more natural way: a “Boolean” attribute is just a name (with no need to explain it as a reduced form of name=value syntax).

Comment: @DanDascalescu When using jQuery to set an attribute, you'll have to call .prop('checked', 'checked') because prop('checked') will obviously only retrieve the state of the checkbox and attr won't work. [Attributes vs. Properties: http://api.jquery.com/prop/  ]

Answer (score 27):

```
<!-- Default to unchecked -->
<input type="checkbox">

<!-- Default to checked, XHTML -->
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />

<!-- Default to checked, HTML5 -->
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

Answer (score 13):

`Checked` is a boolean attribute in HTML 5. A true value is indicated by the attribute being present, and a false value is indicated by its absence. If it is present, its value should either be empty or set to the property name `checked="checked"`. Either of these forms are correct:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: This is one of the best examples of why design (fail) by committee can be a bad thing.  True/false for the value makes great intuitive sense, but I guess W3C didn't think that was confusing enough.

Comment: @Gamadril Thanks! I've updated the URL in my answer. In the future, feel free to make edits like this yourself. Collaboration is what makes answers on this site great.

Answer (score 5):

You care about XHTML-compatibility in HTML5, if you are creating documents that use the XHTML serialization of HTML5, either exclusively by serving the document with an `application/xhtml+xml` mime type, or creating a polyglot document that can be served either as `application/xhtml+xml` or as `text/html` (the 'normal' html mime-type).

If you are only using `text/html`, then you do not need to care about XHTML syntax. However, you *may* use XML-style self-closing syntax when embedding SVG or MathML in your page. (SVG is widely supported in the latest browsers, MathML less so.) You may also use `/>` to end *void* HTML elements such as meta, link, input, img etc, but this has no effect different from using `>` to end those elements.

A minor comment on terminology. In markup, in common parlance either `checked` or `checked="checked"` is an "attribute". A "property" is something else.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html it's an attribute