# checked="checked" not working in chrome

Tags: html, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Type[]" value="Red" checked="checked" /><span class="space-right">Red</span>
```

Properly sets checkbox to checked in firefox and safari but not chrome. Can't find any info about this online.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Have also tried the naked `checked` as well as `checked="true"`

Not looking for a js solution, thank you.

Edit: The answer by taco below describes what the issue was. When using forms and input elements, the elements must be properly nested in `<td></td>` tags or the `checked="checked"` has no effect. Here is an example of a jsfiddle that proves this to be true on chrome 29.0.1547.57: http://jsfiddle.net/LnL7b/

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zwU43/

Comment: Well, I've just literally copied that line and pasted it in the middle of your question using the Chrome debugger and it showed a Checked checkbox with the word Red...

Comment: I'm using chrome as well and it worked fine. Just use jquery if you aren't getting the results desired.  http://jsfiddle.net/HnEgT/

Comment: "but not Chrome." [Prove it, show us a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Works in Chrome for me. Here are a couple notes on `checked="checked"` vs just `checked` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12331533/1314762

Comment: I guess i need to examine my setup if it is working for everyone else.

Comment: According to the HTML5 spec, `<input>` does not have children, are you thinking of `<label>`?

Comment: @Dai: no, `input` cannot contain any children; but the browsers (`inspect element`) will normally salvage that broken HTML when constructing the DOM and move the `span` to be a sibling of the `input` element.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was able to replicate this issue on Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <input type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" checked="checked">
  </tr>
</table>
```

I broke the table by improperly nesting a radio button. This somehow causes Google Chrome to not mark the input radio as checked.

[jsfiddle example - broken](http://jsfiddle.net/fWH7Q/) and
[jsfiddle example - working](http://jsfiddle.net/fWH7Q/1/)

Comment: Thank you, the issue for me ended up also being improperly nesting the checkbox in a table.

Comment: Apparently still an issue if your input is not properly in the table

Comment: please use checked only not checked="checked"
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp
Thanks

Comment: I can duplicate the same issue using 'checked' and not 'checked=checked'

Answer (score 5):

@Abhay's answer worked for me, I dont know why people negative marking it. I had 2 radio groups sharing same name like below,

```
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
```

Then again at the bottom of the page,

```
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
```

So what happening was browser's getting ambiguity and it was selecting only the bottom one not the upper one.

Hope this will help someone.

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 3):

checked="checked" works fine in Chrome. Make sure you are not having any other issues. Any invalid HTML. No inline element containing block-level elements?

Comment: This is very likely the correct answer - the `<span>Red</span>` inside his `<input>` is invalid, as mentioned in comments above. Probably it's just breaking on the OP's particular build of Chrome.

Comment: I have fixed the HTML and still having the issue. Works fine on jsfiddle but not not the actual webpage.

Comment: Probably you are calling a  javascript function somewhere that unselects all checkboxes after pageload. Or a plugin or if it only apears in chrome try to disable some plugins you are using. Some plugins load unwanted scripts.

Answer (score 3):

Try with tag DIV

```
<div><input type="checkbox" name="ckkhuyenmai" id="ckkhuyenmai" checked>KHUYENMAI</div>
```

It will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You provided a **'checked'** prop to a form field without an 'onChange' handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use **'defaultChecked'**. Otherwise, set either 'onChange' or 'readOnly'.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with **Chrome** and nested **radio elements** outside the `form` tag having bugs.
Consider using input radio or others inside `form` tag

Answer (score 0):

Checked="checked" works fine in Chrome. Ensure that there are not multiples of same name. Also check for hidden ones.

Comment: Not multiples of the same name? The name is used to make radio button groups.

Comment: This is actually worked form me. If there are 2 radio groups having same name, it causes issues. More on this in my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

i know you said you weren't looking to use it but jquery is an option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  div { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Hourly" checked="checked">

    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Daily">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Weekly">

    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Monthly" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Yearly">
  </p>
</form>
<div></div>

<script>
var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
  $( "div" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
};
countChecked();

$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HnEgT/

Hope this helps some what.

Comment: The OP would like to check a specific checkbox but it (mysteriously) doesn't work in his installation of Chrome - does this fix that? It appears to just count the checked inputs. Using `input.prop('checked',true)` instead *might* be a valid solution if the OP was willing to use JS, though.

Comment: How this answer got up-votes is beyond me. Not only does it not answer the question, but it also goes directly against what OP asked for, a non JS solution.

Answer (score -1):

If you have html like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="email">
<input type="checkbox" name="email">
<input type="checkbox" name="email" checked>
```

Then no one will be checked, due to name conflicts.

Comment: This is not an actual answer to the question

Comment: This answer helped me. Getting rid of the same name worked in a set of React based check-boxes