# post pre checked checkbox on form submit PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

how can i submit a pre checked checkbox on submit?

right now i have

```
$checked= 'checked="checked"';
<input type="checkbox" name="entity_id['.$row['entity_id'].']" value="Yes" '.$checked.'>
```

on submit, this is not getting posted, only when checked/unchecked by hand.

my $checked is actually coming from a for-each mysql query.

any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
    <form method="post">';
if($hass_lights == 'Yes'){$user->getLights($userid);}
  exit('

<br><b>Google is requiring access to your basic profile information.</b><br><br>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-text" style="height:40px; width:100px" name="authorized" value="Allow" /> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-text" style="height:40px; width:100px" name="authorized" value="Deny" />
</form>
');

     function getLights($userID){
                $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM hass_entities WHERE id = :id AND devicetype= 'light' ORDER BY friendly_name ASC");
                $stmt->bindParam(':id',$userID);    
                $stmt->execute();
            $userData = $stmt->fetchAll();
            echo '
            <div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" style="width:120px" data-target="#lights">Lights</button>
  <br/><div id="lights" class="collapse"><br/><table border=0>';
            foreach( $userData as $row ) {
if($row['enabled'] == 'Yes'){
$checked = 'checked="checked"'; 
}else{  
$checked = '';       
}
    echo '<tr><td><label id="'.$row['entity_id'].'">'.$row['friendly_name'].' </label></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="entity_id['.$row['entity_id'].']" value="Yes" '.$checked.'></td></tr>'; 
        }
            echo '</table></div></div><br/>';
    }
```

-Dennis

Comment: did you verify `checked="checked"` is also in the browsers html source?

Comment: Show an example of how you're processing this.

Comment: i added the code how i actually using it right now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="entity_id['.$row['entity_id'].']" value="Yes" checked>
```

Comment: it shows as checked, yes, but it does not POST value.

Answer (score 0):

Your input field is been written in an echo statement? Would be good to see the entire form, but here is your code working:

```
<form method=POST>
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$row = [];
$row['entity_id'] = 1;
$checked= 'checked="checked"';
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="entity_id['.$row['entity_id'].']" value="Yes" '.$checked.'>';
?>
<button type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: thanks, but for some reason i do not get a POST from this. only when i uncheck and recheck.

Comment: In this case, I think that the next step is to do a var_dump on $userData to check if the data that is coming from the database is in fact 'Yes' (if($row['enabled'] == 'Yes')). Maybe some lower or uppercase problem.

Comment: yea actually it looks like the error is not on my end but googles since the var_dump is looking great and the json afterwards is valid.

Comment: Check this answer. Seems that this problem occurs when you try to nest the input improperly on a table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18346515/2981425