# Does the li tag have a "dropdown" attribute?

Tags: html, html-lists

Does the `<li>` tag have a `dropdown` attribute? I saw this on StackExchange and I'm wondering if it is valid and what it means. Also I searched on Mozilla Developer Network but nothing mentioned there.

Comment: Where have you seen it?

Comment: `<ul class="dropdown"><li>Option here</li></ul>` is quite popular, if that's what you mean?

Comment: My bad... it was on Github!

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3094

Comment: <li dropdown> ... no class!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does AngularJS get away with using custom HTML5 element tags and attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665303/how-does-angularjs-get-away-with-using-custom-html5-element-tags-and-attributes)

Comment: Since you found nothing on MDN that must mean it is not valid. I think a `li  ` can only have a `value`  attribute as said by MDN.

Comment: @putvande ~ It did look a bit strange but then web technologies change... just had to make sure. Must be a parsing issue... Thanks!

Comment: @TheodoreFox welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions here, you should consider providing details in the question, not asking the question in the title. Also if you saw it somewhere on StackExchange, how about providing a link? Then we can look at that and explain what's going on there.

Comment: @dman2306 ~ Thanks for the suggestions; I'll bear in mind for my second question.

Answer (score -1):

```
<button is="mega-button">
```

is valid html5 and

```
<select name="x"><option selected>name</option></select>
```

is also valid, it seems a bit confusing. For mor information read: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/?redirect_from_locale

Comment: Very thought-provoking but I'm not sure if it is relevant? <li> is not a custom tag and my example was an attribute missing a value?

Comment: <option> is also not an custom element see this post on stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331290/in-html5-to-set-a-checkbox-as-checked-should-i-simply-use-checked-as-a-proper

Comment: Appreciative of the insight!